# How does the way we define cos or tan have anything to do with degrees of the angle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

[image]

So sine of angle $A$ is just a ratio. It is the ratio of the length of the opposite or perpendicular of angle $A$ and the hypotenuse.
Cosine of angle $A$ is also just a ratio. It is the ratio of the length of base of $A$ and the hypotenuse.
Tangent of angle $A$ is the ratio of the length of the perpendicular to $A$ and length of the base of $A$.
So far so good. These are just ratios.
Sine of $A$ makes sense since it determines how big angle $A$ is.
But the cosine of angle $A$ or tangent of $A$ is not intuitive to me.
For example in what way the length of base of $A$ and the hypotenuse's length affect the angle of $A$? Their length doesn't seem relevant to how many degrees it has. Same for tangent.
Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: If you have a fixed hypotenuse and you increase the base, the angle has to decrease. For example, consider a ladder (hypotenuse) resting against a wall (opposite). If you pull the bottom of the ladder away from the wall (increasing the base), the ladder will get lower (decreasing the angle with the floor).

Comment: "For example in what way the length of base of A and the hypotenuse's length affect the angle of A? Their length doesn't seem relevant to how many degrees it has. Same for tangent."  ... Um... why do you think it has no relevence?  Given a hypotentuse there is only one possible right triangle with a given b so the the angle most certainly *is* determined.  Like wise given two legs of a right triangle there is only one right triangle with the sides so the angle is determined.  I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: @Rahul: For a fixed hypotenuse if I increase the base then the right angle is gone right? Take the triangle in my OP. Also in the ladder example the ladder gets lower but hypotenuse increases right?

Comment: @fleablood: I didn't understand this `Given a hypotentuse there is only one possible right triangle with a given b `

Comment: No.  If you have a right angle with a fixed hypotenuse, if you you increase the base then the hypotenuse, like the ladder, slides down the wall causing the angle to lessen.  Consider the triangle 3-4-5 with hypotenuse 5.  Increase the base 4 to 4.5 and the side 3 lessens to 2.179 which means the angle has reduced a bit.

Comment: Given a hypotenuse h and a base b, there is only one possible right triangle:  The one with sides $\sqrt{h^2 - b^2}$, $b$, and $h$.  That one and only one triangle has fixed angles.

Comment: The ladder *is* the hypotenuse.  It stays the same size.  Given a fixed hypotenuse there is a full "circle" of right triangles each with legs a and b with the condition $a^2 + b^2 = hypotenuse^2$.  Each distinct (a,b) value corresponds to one and only one base angle.  ... It's very hard for me to see why this would be difficult to see.

Comment: By "fixed hypotenuse" I meant a hypotenuse of fixed length (but it can slide, like a ladder sliding down a wall: https://learner.org/courses/learningmath/measurement/images/session5/5c1.gif).

Comment: Turn your triangle sideways so that the wall becomes the floor and the floor becomes the wall.  It's the same thing.  If you ladder has a fixed length then each angle cooresponds to exactly one spot on the wall.  But if you look at the floor there is only one possible spot on the floor.  If you change the spot on floor you must change the spot on the wall and change the angle.  Likewise if you change the spot on the wall you must change the spot on the floor and the angle.

Comment: Look at your drawing.  If the perpendicular gets bigger or smaller and the hypotenuse stays the same then the angle gets bigger orsmaller while the base gets smaller of bigger.  Likewise if the base gets smaller or bigger then the angle gets bigger or smaller and the perpendicular gets bigger or smaller.  You can't change one of the three without changing all of the three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s a somewhat different way to define these functions that might make the relationships to sides of triangles clearer.

Consider the unit circle with center $O$ and two rays from $O$ that intersect the circle at points $A$ and $B$, with an acute angle $\theta=\angle AOB$ between them, as shown below.

[image: trig function diagram]

Instead of defining the trigonometric functions as ratios of sides of triangles, define them as the lengths of certain line segments as follows:

- $\sin\theta = \overline{BC}$, the altitude to $\overrightarrow{OA}$ from $B$.
- $\tan\theta=\overline{AD}$, the length of the segment tangent to the circle at $A$ that intersects $\overrightarrow{OB}$ at $D$.
- $\sec\theta=\overline{OD}$, the distance to the intersection of $\overrightarrow{OB}$ with the tangent to the circle at $A$.

The “co” functions are the lengths of the corresponding line segments drawn on the other side of $\overrightarrow{OB}$, using the ray $\overrightarrow{OE}$, which is perpendicular to $\overrightarrow{OA}$.

$\triangle{OCB}$ is congruent to $\triangle{BFO}$, so $\overline{BF}=\overline{OC}$. Moreover, $\overline{OB}=1$, so we have the familiar ratios of sides of a right triangle for the sine and cosine.

Now, $\triangle{OCB}$ and $\triangle{OAD}$ are similar, so $\overline{AD}:\overline{BC}::\overline{OA}:\overline{OC}$ and $\overline{OA}=1$, and we have $$\tan\theta=\overline{AD}={\overline{BC}\over\overline{OC}}={\sin\theta\over\cos\theta}.$$ From these same triangles and the previous equation we find that $$\sec\theta = {\tan\theta\over\sin\theta} = \frac1{\cos\theta}.$$

The remaining two functions can be related to $\triangle{OCB}$ and the other functions via similar considerations.

If we change the radius of the circle, it’s clear that the lengths of all of these line segments change proportionally, i.e., the ratios of their lengths to the radius are constant across similar triangles. Since we’re taking a radius as the hypotenuse of the triangle, this also means that their ratios to the hypotenuse are constant for a given angle, which leads to the more familiar definitions of these functions as ratios of sides of a right triangle.

Comment: How did you demonstrate how the ratios determine the angles. I am not sure what do you try to show me when you define `sin8` as just a length

Comment: @Jim Once these functions are defined in this way for a right triangle with unit hypotenuse, they can be extended to any right triangle via similarity, which gives you the ratios of sides with which you’re already familiar. As far as determining the angles, since you’re working with right triangles, the lengths of any two sides uniquely determine the length of the third via the Pythagorean theorem, and so also determine all of the angles of the triangle. Starting with lengths instead of ratios should make this fairly obvious.

Comment: The idea behind this answer is actually exactly what you're looking for. It defines the $\cos$ function in a way that is not dependent on a ratio. Since angles are best understood in terms of circles, this approach allows one to see the conn between the angle and the trig functions more directly.

Answer (score 1):

Every right angle with have distinct sides a, b, and hypotenuse h, *always* with the condition $a^2 + b^2 = h^2$.  Each triangle with an (a,b,h) sides will have a distinct angle with with a one-to-one coorespondence between angle $\theta$ and the set of $(a/h, b/h, 1)$ where $(a/h, b/h, 1)$ represents a class of similar right triangles-- similar up to a scaling factor.

$a/h$ is unique to the angle.  We can that $sin$.  $b/h$ is unique to the angle we call that $cos$.  $a/b = (a/h)/(b/h)$ is also unique.  That is $tan$.

====

You say you understand that $A/H$ determines how big the angle is. But $B/H = \sqrt{1 - A/H}$ by the pythagorean theorem.  If one determines how big the angle is, the other has to also determine how big it is.

Also if you just flip the triangle sideways, the height becomes the base, and the base becomes the height.  So whatever was true about the height of one must be true about the base of the other.

Now if $A/H$ determines how big the angle is, so must $\frac{A/H}{\sqrt{1 - A/H}} = \frac{A/H}{B/H} = A/B = \tan$.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. Could you please clarify a bit the part `will have a distinct angle with with a one-to-one coorespondence between angle θ and the set of (a/h,b/h,1)(a/h,b/h,1) `

Comment: Let's consider for simplicity sake only triangles with fixed hypotenuse h.  Then for a triangle with angle $\theta$ there will be one and only one triangle with sides a,b,h.  And for every triangle with sides a',b', h there will be one and only one angle $\theta'$.   For any given a we can find b= $\sqrt{h^2 -a^2}$ and therefore we can find $\theta$.  For any given b we can find a = $\sqrt{h^2-b^2}$ and therefore find $\theta$.  For any given $a/b = c$ we can solve for $a/\sqrt{h^2 - a^2} = c$ to find out what a and b are and therefore find $\theta$.

Comment: About your point:  "`B/H = sqrt(1 - A/H)`....Don't you mean `sqrt(1 - (A/H)^2)`? I see your point that using the pythagorean theory we end up with a formula that expresses `B/H` in terms of `A/H` but it is not too intuitive, is it?

Comment: Yes, I meant the square.  That was a typo.  As for whether I think that expressing A in terms of B was intuitive.  Yes, I *do* think that is utterly basic and the absolutely fundimental to trigonometry.  So yes, I do expect it to be intuitive.  $sin^2 + cos^2 = 1$ and the trig functions uniquely determined by the angle is *the* idea of trig.  It should become the very *first* thing to consider.

Comment: Even if using the pythagorean theorem isn't intuitive (which it should be) turning a right triangle on its side so that the leg becomes a base and the base becomes a leg should be.